# Parsing a domain name

Tags: c, string

I am parsing the domain name out of a string by `strchr()` the last . (dot) and counting back until the dot before that (if any), then I know I have my domain.

This is a rather nasty piece code and I was wondering if anyone has a better way.

The possible strings I might get are:

- domain.com
- something.domain.com
- some.some.domain.com

You get the idea. I need to extract the "domain.com" part.

Before you tell me to go search in google, I already did. No answer, hence I am asking here.

Thank you for your help

EDIT:

The string I have contains a full hostname. This usually is in the form of whatever.domain.com but can also take other forms and as someone mentioned it can also have whatever.domain.co.uk. Either way, I need to parse the domain part of the hostname: domain.com or domain.co.uk

Comment: what about ccTLDs? do you need `foo.co.uk` or is `co.uk` enough?

Comment: Good point! thanks for pointing that one out

Comment: @Justin Ethier While I do appreciate the correction of typos and a way to make my question more readable, editing the question with no meaningful purpose it's rather annoying.

Comment: @Jessica: from the site faq: Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Comment: @philip, I don't mind people doing whatever they want with the questions I ask, I was just pointing out that editing for the sake of editing add noise and nothing useful. My apologies to you then since this apparently is very important (upper case P is the key here to understand the question).

Comment: I do actually find good spelling and grammar important. But sad, annoying, pedantic people like me don't end up criticising people's spelling and grammar on stack overflow like they might elsewhere, because the spelling and grammar get fixed silently. This means we can all focus on the question at hand.

Comment: And on the subject of the question: I think you'll need to construct a list of domains, and decide which ones need the last 2 fields extracted, and which need the last three. This is made even more complicated by such domains as `bl.uk` (british library) and `parliament.uk`. There's a list at http://tinyurl.com/4tgwb9 (which I got from http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Domain::PublicSuffix)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can now really stop focusing on my spelling (since English is not my native language) and focus on the question. Since I know the users at StackOverflow will correct my spelling. Great! Dit is geweldig

Comment: @Philip. I think I will settle for whatever.com since these are internal domains and not internet ones. Oops, sorry. I meant Internet.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be more helpful. It's a hard problem!

Comment: I appreciate the help Philip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `strrchr()`?

I would probably approach this by doing:

1. `strrchr` to get the last dot in the string, save a pointer here, replace the dot with a NUL (`'\0'`).
2. `strrchr` again to get the *next* to last dot in the string. The character *after* this is the start of the name you are looking for (`domain.com`).
3. Using the pointer you saved in #1, put the dot back where you set it NUL.

Beware that names can sometimes end with a dot, if this is a valid part of your input set, you'll need to account for it.

**Edit**: To handle the flexibility you need in terms of example.co.uk and others, the function described above would take an additional parameter telling it how many components to extract from the end of the name.

You're on your own for figuring out how to decide how many components to extract -- as Philip Potter mentions in a comment below, this is a Hard Problem.

Comment: let me try it, however as  Philip Potter mentioned, how can I handle domain.co.uk?

Comment: @Jessica: you need to define what you want more clearly. For example, .jp, .uk, and .au have second-level general domains: co.uk, co.jp, com.au. But others such as .de, .es, .be, .tk don't: amazon.de etc. What exactly do you want? If you want to extract the last "meaningful" part of the domain, it's a Hard Problem.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a reply to the question itself, but an idea for an alternate approach:

In the context of already very nasty code, I'd argue that a good way to make it less nasty, and provide a good facility of parsing domain names and the likes - is to use PCRE or a similar library for regular expressions. That will definitly help you out if you also want to validate that the tld exists, for instance.

It may take some effort to learn initially, but if you need to make changes to existing matching/parsing code, or create more code for string matching - I'd argue that a regex-lib may simplify this a lot in the long term. Especially for more advanced matching.

Another library I recall which supports regex, is glib.

Comment: thanks. I would definatelly try regular expressions, however I can't use any external.

Comment: What does the project currently link with? Libc only?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what flavor of C, but you probably want to tokenize the domain using "." as the separator.

Try this: http://www.metalshell.com/source_code/31/String_Tokenizer.html

As for the domain name, not sure what your end goal is, but domains can have lots and lots of nodes, you could have a domain name foo.baz.biz.boz.bar.co.uk.

If you just want the last 2 nodes, then use above and get the last two tokens.

Comment: just the name.something where the .something can be .com, .net. etc or in the form of .co.uk etc

Comment: I tried before with strtok but I need to keep on reading an saving strings... unless you know a good way to do it

Comment: not sure what your program needs to do, you need to take http://www.foo.bar.co.uk and turn it into co.uk ?

Comment: no, I get a a string containing a full hostname. this usually is in the form of whatever.domain.com but can also take other forms and as someone mentioned it can also have whatever.domain.co.uk. Either way, I need to parse the domain part of the hostnamer: domain.com or domain.co.uk

Comment: should be easy with strtok, use the example I noted, store each token in an array of strings, keep track of the number of tokens. Then just join the last 2 or 3 tokens (depending on extension) for your answer.